# Redux saga: I need to pass argument to axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am migrating my code from thunk to saga because of my companies requirements.

Sending api requests using thunk with params was really easy and I am having a hard time figuring out how to *pass params to the axios request*:

> **redux/sagas/handlers/marketplace.js**

```js
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {
  FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_FAIL,
  FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_REQUEST,
  FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
} from '../../types/marketplaceTypes';
import { fetchAllItemsRequest } from '../requests/marketplace';

export function* fetchAllItems(action) {
  console.log('MARKET PLACE HANDLER', action);
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(fetchAllItemsRequest);
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, '<== error while saga');
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_FAIL,
      error: 'Error loading ITEMS list',
    });
  }
}

export default function* fetchItems() {
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_REQUEST, fetchAllITEMSs);
}
```

> **redux/sagas/requests/marketplace.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchAllApisRequest = (ARGS) => {
  console.log(ARGS);  // Need to pass them from components
  return axios.request({
    method: 'get',
    url: uri,
  });
};
```

> **rootSaga.js**

```js
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { fetchAllItems } from '../sagas/handlers/marketplace';

export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([fetchAllItems()]);
}
```

---

And finaly, how i am dispatching:

> **Component.js**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_REQUEST,
  })
}, [])  // NOT SURE HOW TO SEND ARGUMENT TO THE AXIOS REQUEST FROM HERE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @markerikson says in his answer, [call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args) allows you to pass in whatever arguments you need to the called function. So if those arguments are known in advance for each time you want to execute this saga, you can just do:

```
const { data } = yield call(fetchAllItemsRequest, AXIOS_ARGS);
```

But you ask how to do it from the `dispatch` call inside `useEffect`, as if you might need to call the same saga (by dispatching the same action type) with different arguments.

In that case, you can simply include them as part of your "action payload", since `takeLatest` (and all similar functions) passes the entire action to the saga. So you could do it something like this.

In the component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_REQUEST,
    args: argsINeedForThisRequest
  })
}, [])
```

and in the saga `fetchAllItems`:

```
export function* fetchAllItems(action) {
  console.log('MARKET PLACE HANDLER', action);
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(fetchAllItemsRequest, action.args); // use action payload here
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, '<== error while saga');
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_ALL_ITEMS_FAIL,
      error: 'Error loading ITEMS list',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Zigmound, thanksfor the detailed explanation. ERROR : I am getting `action` (the one consoled out) in the fetchAllItems saga as `undefined`.

Comment: @KaranKumar I notice you've edited your original post now, but I looked just before you edited and saw the problem: you were passing `fetchAllItems()` as the second argument to `takeLatest`, when it should simply be `fetchAlltems`. Your current version has typos so it's hard to see what you're currently doing, but this change should fix the `undefined` error you mention.

Comment: Yes, also, I had a typo in the rootSaga as well, I am using `{ fetchAllItems }` instead of importing default `fetchItems`. It worked, thanks alot !!

Answer (score 0):

The saga `call` effect allows passing function arguments as additional parameters after the method to call.

So, if you had this in your original JS code:

```js
axios.post('/some/url', data)
```

it would be this in a saga:

```js
yield call(axios.post, '/some/url', data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how do i pass from `Component ===> sagas/requests/marketplace.js` which is consuming the params/args